# Token Swapping Mechanisim

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, uniswap

Hey Techies Nice to meet you all . I need your help . Actually i  want to create  a swapping mechanisim on my dapp  for example:we have items by which a user can buy a items   by paying in glmr. let's say if user come to my website and if he  has glmr tokens then he can buy   our product. but if he  have only other crypto  lets's say if  he had ether coin on etherium
then he can swap his  ether tokens to glmr by using your api and further he can buy  items using
glmr.please let me know if  you have such solutions.Looking for your reply with hope

Answer (score 0):

I think the best would be to use some existing token swapping APIs, e.g.,

- [Uniswap API](https://docs.uniswap.org/protocol/V2/guides/interface-integration/using-the-api)
- [Kaleido API](https://api.kaleido.io/tokenswap.html)